# Copying Excel from Template xls

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I have a template xls to which I write some data. This template needs to be saved in different folder under different name. Here is code I use:

```
        Excel::load('template.xls', function($excel) use($order) {
            // Writing stuff

        })->store('xls', public_path('exports'));
```

How do I change this code to write file under different name? I now it's trivial but I couldn't find it in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested it but try this:

```
Excel::load('template.xls', function($excel) use($order) {
        // Writing stuff

})->setFileName('new-filename')->store('xls', public_path('exports'));
```

**Note** that you shouldn't need to specify an file extension

Comment: Needed to change setFilename to setFileName and it works, thx